# Transmission Bus Admittance Question

Tags: impedance, generator, bus, line, admittance

I have a question about calculating the admittance between buses in the single line diagram shown below:

[image]

The solution I have been given shows that the admittance between bus 2-2 is found by adding the admittance between bus 2-5 and bus 2-4. Is this correct?

Why do we need to be calculate the admittance between bus 2-2? I thought we would only require calculating the admittance between different buses?

Thanks

Comment: That is correct if you are talking about the on diagonal element of the bus admittance matrix.  Otherwise, I don’t understand your nomenclature (bus 2-2) when compared to the drawing

Comment: @relayman357 Yeah I do not understand it either. I will add an answer to the post if I manage to get it sorted.